# I try to substitute some text in highlighted text in Vim

Tags: vim

I try to select some text in a sentence and substitute an character in the range of the highlighted text.

e.g.

This is my masterpiece document $which$ has many dollar signs on it. $For example$

I only highlight `$For example$` and try to substitute **two dollars signs** with '|'

I have tried the following command:

```
:'<,>'s/\$/\|/gc <CR>
```

I use `'v'` to highlight in **normal**

But above command replaces **all the dollar signs** in the sentence with '|' instread
This is what I got after above command:

This is my masterpiece document |which| has many signs on it. |For example|

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with my substitute command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the selection made, type

```
s/\%Vpattern/replace
```

So in your case

```
:'<,>'s/\%V\$/\|/gc <CR>
```

Note if you are doing a very magic search (`\v` at the beginning of the search), omit the backslash and just type `%V`

`:h \%V` explains it pretty well:

> Match inside the Visual area.

Vim is not very user friendly in general and things you expect to work, like replacing inside a selection, are not automatic.

If the main thing you do with selected text is a replacement, this mapping might be useful, which always prefixes the search with `\%V` when you type `:` when visual mode is active.

```
" Turn on "match inside visual selection" by default when pressing
" : with text highlighted
vnoremap : :\%V
```